# PySpark doesn't have getVectors method accessible for Word2VecModel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to access the `getVectors()` method of pyspark 1.2.0 Spark version but pyspark states -

```
input.cache()
word2vec = Word2Vec()
model = word2vec.fit(input)
vector = model.getVectors()

AttributeError: 'Word2VecModel' object has no attribute 'getVectors'
```

So do I have only way to access this using Scala/Java or there is something I can do.

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to create a reproducable code with a toy file run on Spark 1.2

```
# cat data.txt
crazy crazy fox jumped
crazy fox jumped
fox is fast
fox is smart
dog is smart

>> lines = sc.textFile('data.txt', 1);
>> lines.collect()
[
 u'crazy crazy fox jumped', 
 u'crazy fox jumped', 
 u'fox is fast', 
 u'fox is smart', 
 u'dog is smart'
]

from pyspark.mllib.feature import Word2Vec       
model = Word2Vec().fit(lines)
```

Now if I run `dir(model)` the output is

```
['__class__',
 '__del__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_java_model',
 '_sc',
 'call',
 'findSynonyms',
 'transform']
```

of which last 3 are the member methods and getvectors() is not a part of that.

Answer (score 0):

getVectors was added to pyspark in version 1.4